# Table Rates Item vs Destination

Tags: table-rates

I want to use Item vs Destination as my shipping fee calculate

but the problem is I have 30~50 destination and my store can buy 50 items in an order

so I need to set 30*50=1500 raw to define my shipping fee rule
Is this the only way? or I should use another way to do it?

Ex:

| COUNTRY REGION | STATE ZIP | POSTAL CODE | Items COUNT | SHIPPING PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | A | A | 1 | 10 |
| USA | A | B | 2 | 20 |
| USA | A | C | 3 | 30 |
| USA | B | A | 1 | 10 |
| USA | B | B | 2 | 20 |
| USA | B | C | 3 | 30 |

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that using the table rates.
The table rates will always use the last available value if there is no record in the database for a specific configuration.
What you can do is create your own shipping method. This is not that hard.
See a tutorial here on how to do it.
The only thing you need to customize is the collectRates method in the shipping model.
Here is how it can look in your case.

```
public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request) {
    // skip if not enabled
    if (!Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/active')) {
        return false;
    }
    // this object will be returned as result of this method
    // containing all the shipping rates of this method
    $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
    $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');
    $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
    $method->setCarrierTitle('Some title here');
    $method->setMethod($this->_code);
    $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));
    //get qty in cart
    $qty = $request->getPackageQty()
    //calculate the price
    $price = 2 + $qty; //3 for 1 item, 4 for 2 items and so on. You can even insert here a calculation algorithm based on config values or what ever comes to mind.
    $method->setPrice($price);
    $result->append($method);
    return $result;
}
```